# Angular 2 add function

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-forms, angular2-services

I'm working on a angular 2 application. Now I would like to do the CRUD "create" operation. But it doesn't work. When I debug the project, it doesn't go to the controller method.

The error in console is "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)"

"EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Response with status: 500 Internal Server Error for URL:" But the url is correct.

```
Component.ts

 onSubmit(value: any) {
        this.submitted = true;
        this.msgs = [];
        this.msgs.push({ severity: 'info', summary: 'Success', detail: 'Form Submitted' });
        console.log(value.description)
        this.periodService.addPeriods(value).then(period => this.period = period);
    }

Controller

  public ActionResult AddPeriod(PeriodModel period)
        {

            period.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
            var periodDto = (APAPeriodDto)period;
            periodDto.State = EntryState.Added;
            this.ServiceLocator.GetService<IAppraisalService>().SavePeriod(periodDto);
            periodDto.VersionNo++;
            return Json(new PeriodModel(periodDto));
        }

service.ts

   addPeriods(period: any) {
        console.log(period)
        console.log("hualala")
        return this.http.post('./Appraisal/AddPeriod', period).toPromise()
            .then(res => <Period>res.json().data)
            .then(data => { return data; });
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**500 Internal Server Error** - means that request was send to server but on the server error happens. If you are are not writing backend you need to talk to developer who do to see what error is.

To get more about an error open developer console (f12 in chrome), then go to network tab, click on your request and then go to preview it should show you more information about server error. Because error is on server side

Comment: I have something similar for delete operations and it goes to the controller function, so i'm not sure why it doesn't work for the add function.

Comment: the preview error is The required anti-forgery form field "__RequestVerificationToken" is not present.

Comment: Hi, i've managed to solve it after checking the network tab. thanks :)